# FOSUserBundle : Overriding a Twig template : adding HTML elements

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I'm using **FOSUserBundle**, and I want to add a few HTML elements to the registration form. Actually, I did and I can see the added properties to the User class in my form. The issue is that I want those fields (first name, last name, date of birth, etc..) to get the **look and feel** of my CSS template (bootstrap).
I succeeded to do that for the login page by overriding it, since the HTML are explicitly declared. I want to do the same for the register page, however it seems confused to me, because here's the content of :

- **register.html.twig**

  {% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

  {% block fos_user_content %}
  {% include "FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig" %}
  {% endblock fos_user_content %}
- **register_content.html.twig**

  {% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

  {{ form_widget(form) }}

How can I access to the elements that I see in the page from this code ?

Comment: downvoted because your question was actually: "how do i set the class on the label of a repeated password field in symfony2?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="form-group {% if form.plainPassword.first.vars.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
  <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password:</label>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
    {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control input-lg', 'placeholder': 'Enter password', 'required': 'required'}}) }}
    {% for errorItem in form.plainPassword.first.vars.errors %}
      <label class="control-label has-error" for="{{ form.plainPassword.vars.id }}">{{ errorItem.message }}</label>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
    {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control input-lg', 'placeholder': 'Enter password again', 'required': 'required'}}) }}
  </div>
</div>
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the official documentation here: "[Overriding Forms](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md)". You will need to create a custom registration form type class, declare it as a service, and tell FOSUserBundle to use it.

To customize the template, see "[Overriding Templates](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md)". In your case, you could create `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/register.html.twig`.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, and as I said, I can see my new form with the new properties I added. But what I want is to access to the HTML code in order to modify the CSS properties. Adding classes for HTML elements, etc.

Comment: Dylan, you might haven't read what I said. I'm using FOSUserBundle, and I overrided the defualt registration form. Take a look at the code above. The form is returned by the method `form_widget(form)`. There aren't any HTML nodes so that I can apply some CSS on them.

Comment: so this has nothing to do with FOSUserBundle, but symfony forms in general.

Answer (score 2):

replace `form_widget(form)` with something like:

```
form_widget(form.username)
form_widget(form.email)
form_widget(form.plainPassword)
form_widget(form.myField)
form_rest(form)
```

in your custom `RegistrationFormType` class, you could add a class to the username field with:

```
    $builder
        ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle', 'attr' => array('class'=>'myClass')))
```

also see form docs on rendering fields by hand: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-a-form-in-a-template

Comment: I did that, but I still have a problem concerning the password field. here's its code :
`->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
             //'attr' => array('class' => 'label label-info')
            ));`
I want to add a class for both password fields

Comment: But when I add the class, it doesn't work, because the class is only for labels. Besides, the plainPassword is a repeated field here. So what do you think I can do to solve that ?

Comment: easiest thing for you to do is to copy the html generated by ``form_widget(form.plainPassword)``, paste into the form template, edit to your heart's desire, and remove ``form_widget(form.plainPassword)``.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I addressed this problem using FOSUserBundle, PUGXMultiUserBundle & BraincraftedBoostrapBundle:

Per FOSUserBundle documentation, add a UserBundle as a child of FOSUser. Create a custom `RegistrationFormType` that includes the following, where only the `attr` and `label_attr` arrays are added:

```
$builder
        ->add('email', 'email', array(
            'label' => 'form.email',
            'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'E-mail',
            ),
            'label_attr' => array(
                'class' => 'sr-only',
    )))
        ->add('username', null, array(
            'label' => 'form.username',
            'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Username',
            ),
            'label_attr' => array(
                'class' => 'sr-only',
    )))
        ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
            'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password',
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'Password',
                ),
                'label_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'sr-only',
                )),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation',
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'Confirm password',
                ),
                'label_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'sr-only',
                )),
            'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
        ))
;
```

The registration form template then looks like this:

```
<form action="{{ path('volunteer_registration') }}" method="POST" class="form-inline">
    {{ bootstrap_set_style('form-inline') }}
    {{ form_row(form.firstName) }}
    {{ form_row(form.lastName) }}
    {{ form_row(form.username) }}
    {{ form_row(form.email) }}
    <br/>
    {{ form_row(form.plainPassword) }}
    {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.second) }}
    {{ bootstrap_set_style('') }}
```